# Finding the number of matrices of rank $3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am stuck on the following problem :

> What is the number of matrices of  rank $3$ in $A$ where $A$ is the space of all $4 \times 3$ matrices with entries in the finite field of three elements ?

The options are :

> 1. $(3^4-3)(3^4-3^2)(3^4-3^3)$
> 2. $(3^4-1)(3^4-3)(3^4-3^2)$
> 3. $3^4(3^4-1)(3^4-2)$
> 4. $(3^4-1)(3^4-2)(3^4-3)$

I will be grateful if someone shows me the way. Thanks and regards.

Comment: @user53386 do you have its answer key in the book where you found this? I think I have figured out, but the key will help to be sure enough..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT**

Here's the sort of thinking that you will be doing.

1. Count the number of ways you can make a nonzero row for your matrix.
2. Count the number of ways you can make a row that is linearly independent of the first row.
3. Count the number of ways you can make a row that is linearly independent of the first two rows.
4. Multiply these choices together.

A big hint for part 2 is that a vector being linearly dependent with another vector means one is a multiple of the other. How many 'multiples' can you have over the finite field of three elements?